# Abstract question about convergence/divergence for the sum from n=0 to infinity of C-nx^n

Tags: convergence-divergence, definition

If the sum from n=0 to infinity of C_n(-3)^n converges and we know that the radius=3, what can be said about the convergence of the sum from n=0 to infinity of  C_n3^n?

I came up with the sum from n=0 to infinity for C_n3^n could be convergent or divergent. With the original centered at zero, and R=3, so the interval could be [-3,3] or [-3,3). Am I on the right track or way off?

Comment: Consider the power series $\sum_n \frac {x^n}n$. Its radius of convergence is $1$. What do you know about the two series $\sum_n \frac1n$ and $\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}n$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would  1/n be 1 and ((-1)^n)/n be (-1,1)?